# have syntax error while executing statement in python

Tags: python

```
>>> x=5
>>> y=10
>>> if(x>y):
... print 'x is greater':
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print 'x is greater':
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear...

Comment: can u pls edit that code ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: You need to use indentation to denote block start/end. *Even when using the interactive interpreter*

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all. Python uses indentation to handle blocks, and since your `print` statement should be inside the `if`'s block, it should be indented:

```
>>> x=5
>>> y=10
>>> if(x>y):
...     print 'x is greater': # Note the indentation here
```